# TYPO3 9 getting queryparameters in typoscript

Tags: typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 < 9 it was possible to set conditions in typoscript using query parameters like this:

// Set a condition when news extension plugin parameter "news" is set, e.g. url:
// www.mysite.com?tx_news_pi1[news]=8

```
 [globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]

...

[global]
```

with realurl you could rewrite the url to a pretty url and the above condition stil worked.

Now, in TYPO3 9 i don't use realurl anymore to rewrite the url, but the native rewriting module.

The condition does not work anymore.

As well using the new new symphony query language conditions does not work here:

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]
...
[global]
```

I debugged the request condition code, there are no query parameters.
But in the news controller they arrive.

Question is:
How can I set a condition like above to respond to extension query parameters in TYPO3 9 using the native url rewriting?

Answer (score 1):

The old TYPOscript condition can be rewritten with this, but your example should work as well:

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
...
[END]
```

See [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85829-ImplementSymfonyExpressionLanguageForTypoScriptConditions.html#general-usage).

According to different configurations for news urls, you can set the `limitToPages` parameter in the sites YAML file, since there is no `ext:realurl` anymore:

Example:

```
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPluginOne:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    limitToPages: [20]
    routes:
      ...
  NewsPluginTwo:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    limitToPages: [21]
    routes:
      ...
```

With the above configuration you set different settings for the news url on the detail page with the id=20 and id=21.